# How do I override Python's 'str' so that it returns a capitalized value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

How do I define

```
class CapStr(str):
    # ...
```

in Python (3.7+) so that all letters in the resulting `str` subclass are capitalized, e.g.

```
>>> foo: CapStr = CapStr('aBcd')
>>> foo
'ABCD'
>>> CapStr('wXyZ')
'WXYZ'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `__new__` method of a subclass of `str` to wrap its superclass's `__new__` method with an uppercased value:

```
class CapStr(str):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return super().__new__(cls, value.upper())
```

so that:

```
>>> CapStr('aBcd')
'ABCD'
```

Comment: Since you can call `str` on things other than strings (e.g. numbers, lists, etc.) which don't need to have an `upper()` method, perhaps you should do `returns super().__new__(cls, value).upper()`? That is, call `str` on the thing first, then call `upper` on the result!

Comment: I'd rather overload `__init__` than `__new__`

Comment: @Demi-Lune: Strings are immutable, so you can't usually do useful things to them in `__init__`.

Comment: @Blckknght Calling `upper` creates a new `str` object, so your method would end up returning an `str` object rather than a `CapStr` object, which would not be ideal if the OP intends to do more than just capitalizing the input with this subclass. I would convert the input `value` to `str` first if implicit conversion is desired: `return super().__new__(cls, str(value).upper())`

Comment: @Blckknght , thanks for pointing this out (the immutable subtlety). Btw, it wasn't 100% clear whether the question was "print and repr self as all caps" or "make sure it is internally stored as all caps". This is a very nice example of using `__new__`

Comment: @blhsing I'm not sure I understand. When I `foo = CapStr('abc')` (as in the answer) I can `foo.some_capstr_method()`. Why is the conversion needed and what am I missing if I don't do it?

Comment: @Demi-Lune Good point: Make sure it's internally stored as all caps.